# How to run Python 2.7 pyd in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pyd

I have a python 2.7 pyd file (= DLL), that I need to run in a python 3 program.
Since it's a pyd, I cannot convert it to python 3 with 2to3.

As of now, I'm running it manually in a separate python console, with an infinite loop waiting for messages from the main program, through TCP. That's really messy, I'd like to have a clean way of doing it.

So how can I run python2 pyd in python 3?